# How do I find the index of a regex match in a string?

Tags: php, regex

In php, it's fairly simple to find and capture all substrings that match a given regex, but is there a simple way to find the index of the first regex match in a string?

i.e. I'd like something that operates like this:

```
$str = "123456789abcdefgh";
$index = preg_index("#abcd#", $str);
// $index == 9
```

Comment: Have you tried [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Comment: `strpos()` only does string matching, not regular expressions, though you could do it on the match, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag with [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = "123456789abcdefgh";
$index = -1;
if(preg_match("#abcd#", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $index = $matches[0][1];
}
```

The `[0]` above corresponds to the capture group inside the regex whose index you want (`0` for the whole expression, `1` for the first capturing group if it exists, etc) while the `[1]` is a fixed index, as documented.

**Edit:** Added an `if` to make the code more presentable, it now doesn't take for granted that the pattern will definitely match.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Nn6jT)**.

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for.